# Ajax and Fancybox form redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

So I had the bright idea to use fancybox and jquery to send a form via AJAX. The form actually displays quite nicely. However when the form is submitted, the user is always redirected. I've tried to mitigate this several ways but to no avail. It's been a while since I've used jQuery so it may be something stupid. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong.

Here's the code, to the best of my knowledge it should prevent the form from redirecting:

```
    $('#fancybox-wrap #email_form').bind('submit', function(){
        $.fancybox.showActivity();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        form_data[crap] = 'Crap';

        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            cache   : false,
            url     : "<?php echo site_url('inventory/email'); ?>",
            data    : form_data,
            success: function(data) {
                $.fancybox(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

If there are any better ways to do this I would glad to  hear them. Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined the variable `crap`? Or is that just for demonstration purposes?

Comment: It's just there for demonstration purposes. If I remove that part, the same thing happens. I'm at a complete loss. It functions correctly [here](http://fancybox.net/blog) and I'm doing almost exactly the same thing. Would the actual page I'm using this on help?

Comment: Yes, it would help. I tried your exact code on a test page, and it worked fine.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://santiam.info/inventory/truck/26) It's the email a friend button towards the bottom. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like your selector is wrong — `#email_form` is the `div` that contains the form, so it cannot take a `submit` event. Try changing the selector to `$('#fancybox-wrap #email_form form')`.

Comment: Thanks Josh. That was the first part of it. The second part of the fix was using 'live' instead of 'bind'. As the email form is recreated by fancybox, I assume that that the bind somehow didn't bind to the recreated form. I think anyway, does that sound right to you? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. I've posted our discussion as an answer for anyone who happens across this question in the future. Glad we could work out the problem! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer stems from the discussion between myself and MackDaddy in the comments of the question.)

The problem here is not that Ajax or Fancybox has interrupted the intended flow of the form (stopping it from following its `action`), but rather simply that:

1. The selector is wrong, since `div#email_form` is not the form itself, but rather its container, and therefore cannot take a `submit` event; and
2. Fancybox appears to remove the `div` and replace it elsewhere inside its own containers. Therefore, the use of the [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function does not work as expected, since the element it attaches to is removed from the DOM and a duplicate is inserted. The [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) function should be used instead, since it will attach the event not only to the first `#email_form`, but all subsequent ones that are inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `action="javascript: void(0)"` in your form?

Comment: That will, of course, prevent the form from submitting, but so should `return false`. There is probably something else wrong with it.

Comment: That is true, I forgot you can just return false on submit.